# Java Swing - UI Block

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, concurrency, block

I have a GUI and on click event, I am calling database queries to generate multiple charts. I cannot see any chart until all the charts are get completed means there is some problem with GUI components which moves to the next chart before the first chart get complered and show it's contents. What could be the possible reason and how to avoid such problem ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no problem with the components. There is a problem with your design. You're doing the long-running queries and the updates of the charts in a single method run in the event dispatch thread. By doing so, the EDT is completely blocked and can't repaint anything until all the queries have been run and all the charts have been generated.

Use a background thread to execute the queries, and generate a chart, in the EDT, each time one query is finished. The SwingWorker class helps doing that. Read [its API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), and [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) about concurrency in Swing.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I had the same felling. Please find below what I am doing btnGenerateGraph.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { //Generate Graphs for MYSQL mysqlGrpahGenerator.generateMYSQLGraph(); luceneGraphGenerator.generateLuceneGraph(); }); Where you want me to change in the code ?

Comment: So, you've already read the javadoc and the tutorial I linked to? If not, then read them. It's all explained in there. If you already read them, then re-read them, since you don't seem to have understood what they explained.

Comment: Well, I red it and I know what is the problem. Now I want to make the change in my code but I am not getting where should I update the code. Actually the method generateMYSQLGraph(); generate 8-10 graphs and it's like I have to use run 8-10 times :(

Comment: take look at the SwingWorker class